# Check broken external image error before showing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to check if an **external** image exists, before showing it. Here's my code:

```
<a href="#" class="gallery hidden">
  <img src="//abc.com/1.jpg" class="room-image">
</a>
<a href="#" class="gallery hidden">
  <img src="//xyz.com/2.jpg" class="room-image"> <!-- not found -->
</a>
<a href="#" class="gallery hidden">
  <img src="//def.com/3.jpg" class="room-image"> <!-- not found -->
</a>
<a href="#" class="gallery hidden">
  <img src="//mno.com/4.jpg" class="room-image">
</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".room-image").error(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
  $(".room-image").parent().removeClass('hidden');
</script>
```

[jsFiffled here](http://jsfiddle.net/tdBmR/2/)

I want to check all images, remove those broken, and show the rest. But this script I have written will be executed almost instantly, because `.removeClass()` runs faster than the `.error()`. This results in seeing the view removes broken image one by one.

How do I do it once, so that the user doesn't see anything being removed dynamically? Thanks.

Comment: Not in <head> because it is a partial loaded dynamically with ajax.

Comment: Updated. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
jQuery(function () {
    $(".room-image").error(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }).on('load', function () {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('hidden');
    }).each(function () {
        //to handle image which are already loaded - before page load
        if (this.complete) {
            if (this.width) {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mA3HP/)

Comment: One note: those images are external. So I am still seeing it being dynamically removed.

Comment: Updated question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Front-end management for dead/empty content is a bad designer habbit.

You can build a function to :

- hide outter container
- render accessible images only (see Arun P Johny's answer)
- show outter container

User Arun P Johny also [suggested a good code for stacking functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033456/executing-one-function-after-another) one after the other.

I edited for your needs

```
function mainFunction() {
    function hideContainer(){
       // hide the outter container
    }
    function removeBroken(){
       // remove broken images like upper answer
    }
    function showContainer(){
       // you guessed
    }
    $.when(hideContainer()).done(removeBroken).done(showContainer);
}
```

---

If you want to do it once so the user doesn't see anything being removed dynamically, you will have to do it server-side.

Comment: I would have to get the image twice if I did it on server-side. Thanks for preparing the fiddle.

Comment: Those images are external images, not in the server.